# Copy 2D array to another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy the values of the cells from several 2D array, which are in the middle of the final sheet(  generated by a functions, with the help of several sheet that contains data ) to another sheet that will give back this data after the execution of the funcions to avoid crushing the data, because i didnt found solution for [my last questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266450/updating-final-sheet-without-losing-data) .

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I read and re-read your question (and the other one) but still I don't understand what you really want to do... merging arrays and write that to a sheet is fairly basic when arrays have tha same width , is that the idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this is what your after but I found this on the Google developers site:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getSheets()[0];
var destination = ss.getSheets()[1];

var range = source.getRange("B2:D4");

// This copies the data in B2:D4 in the source sheet to
// D4:F6 in the second sheet
range.copyValuesToRange(destination, 4, 6, 4, 6);
```

[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyValuesToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyValuesToRange%28Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer%29)

Hope this helps.

Comment: B2:D4 is it an array ?
in ( ss.getSheets()[0] ) how to mention the sheet if we have her name or how to get the number of the sheet we want ? 
and thanks for your help

Comment: Hi arb,  using getRange() just sets up a range reference for any of the range methods.  The following code would create a 2D array of the data held in the cells B2:D4

Comment: Sorry about that the code would be var data = source.getRange('B2:D4').getValues();

Comment: Actually, I don't have constant number ( 2 and 4  in your example ) but they are variable, and the problem is that ("Bvar:Dvar2") didnt work. @Jay

Comment: Sorry just posted that example before I'd read your comment, you can set ranges using getRange(rowNumber, columNumber, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns) eg B2:D4 would be getRange(2, 2, 3, 3)

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a quick example that might help.  The data in the example I want to find is '2b2' located in the second sheet of a four sheet spreadsheet. I want to copy the column it is in to the 4th sheet. It's not pretty but it does the job. :-)

```
function testCopy() {
  //get the active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 //create an array of all the sheets in our spreadsheet
 var sheets = ss.getSheets();

 // Declare the destination sheet to copy the data to
 var destination = sheets[3];

 //create an index for the sheet that hold the data we want to copy
 var targetSheet = 0;

//loop through each of the sheets to check for the data we are looking for
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length -1; i++) {

  // Create a 2D array that holds all of the data we want to test from the sheet
  var rowData = sheets[i].getRange('A1:C3').getValues();

  //Loop through each row of data in the 2D array
  for (j = 0; j < rowData.length; j++) {

    // Create an array of the cells in the row
    var cells = rowData[j];

   //loop through each of the cells
   for (k = 0; k < cells.length; k++) {

    // check to see if the cell has the data we are looking for and if so set the   
    // target sheet index to the current sheet
    if (cells[k] == '2b2'){
      targetSheet = i;
    }
   }
  }
}

//set the range of the data we want copy for this example a single column
var copyRange = sheets[targetSheet].getRange('B1:B3');

// copy the data to the destination sheet into D4:D6
copyRange.copyValuesToRange(destination, 4, 4, 4, 6);

}
```

Don't quite know what has happened to the indentation. :-(